# Is there a benefit of using <input> rather than <textArea>?

Tags: html, text, input, textarea, generator

I'm writing a basic text generator and in some of the fields, I needed to allow the user to write more than a single line. I know that  doesn't allow multiple lines so I had to use  but I was wondering if there was a benefit to using `<input>`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a large number of functional differences between `input` and `textarea` elements. For example, for `input`, you can specify the required pattern of input data or to provide a set of author-supplied alternatives in addition to letting the use enter his own choice.

However, if you need to let the user enter an unlimited number of input lines and to type a long piece of text in a reasonable way, you more or less need to switch from `input` to `textarea` (or to a contenteditable block).

On the other hand, if the input consists of *separate lines*, like a postal address or a list on entries, one entry per line, rather than freely flowing text, `input` elements may be more practical.